# @Vue/test-utils: findAll() always returning 0 element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm building a feedback rating component with stars icons, but when I test to check if the correct number of stars are being rendered depending on the prop *length*, wrapper.findAll('svg') always returns 0 element. Here is the code:

**VueRating.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="rating-container">
    <svg
      v-for="item in length"
      :key="item"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="23"
      height="23"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100"
    >
      <polygon
        class="polygon"
        ref="polygonRef"
        points="50,0 64,36 100,42 72,64 78,100 50,80 22,100 28,64 0,42 36,36"
        fill="none"
        stroke="#000"
        stroke-width="1"
      />
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps} from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  length: {
    type: Number,
    default: 5,
  }
});
</script>
```

**VueRating.spec.js**

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import VueRating from "../../src/components/VueRating.vue";

describe("VueRating.vue", () => {
  it("should render props.length star(s) when mounted",() => {
    const wrapper = mount(VueRating, {
      props: {
        length: 3,
      },
    });
    expect(wrapper.findAll("svg").length).toBe(3);
    //expect(wrapper.findAll(".rating-container svg").length).toBe(3);
    //expect(wrapper.findAll(".polygon").length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

[image: Test failing in the console]

Thank you!

I tried finding by multiple selectors but without avail

Comment: Try to log the wrapper html like `console.log(wrapper.html())` before expect and give us the output

Comment: Hello Brahim, thank you for commenting.
This is what is being logged:
console.log
    <div class="rating-container" length="3"></div>

Comment: It looks like the component is not mounted correctly

Comment: What could possibly ruin the mounting process? I double-checked the syntax and it looks correct

Comment: Did it display correctly when you use it?

Comment: In the browse it renders it completely fine!

Comment: Try to add the vue test utils dependency to this playground and paste your component then give me the new link https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-rlwqde?file=test%2Fbasic.test.ts&initialPath=__vitest__/

Comment: I'm having some troubles editing the file. Here is what I've done: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-ygvrof?file=test%2Fbasic.test.ts,src%2FVueRating.vue&initialPath=__vitest__/

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it locally on my machine

Comment: I reproduced it locally and it works fine

Comment: Really? Did you use the same code as the one provided on this question form? (not the one on the Stackblitz)

Comment: Yes it's this code

Comment: This is so weird, because i've just tested it again locally and still the test fails

Comment: Try it in vue fresh project

Comment: I tried it but still the same issue. Jest always returns 0

Comment: can you share a repo for reproduction?

Comment: https://github.com/Achraffawzi/vue-rating/tree/main

Comment: I recommend to use vite and vitest